# Sending JSON data via GET method in Django API but not receiving it in backend

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an API in Django.
I am sending json data via get method but not receiving data in backend.

I tried send data through requests.get(url, json={"query":"Hello"}) method,
Same should be received in django backend.

```
client.py

import requests

endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
response = requests.get(endpoint,json = {"query":"Hello"})
print((response.text))
print(response.json()['Message'])
print(response.status_code)
```

```
views.py

import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def api_home(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # request --> HttpRequest -->Django
    print(dir(request))
    body = request.body
    print(body) # byte string of JSON Data   
    
    print("Request Received.....")
    print("Responding.....")
    return JsonResponse({"Message" : "Hi there, this is your django api response"})
```

```
Output in Client.py terminal

{"Message": "Hi there, this is your django api response"}
Hi there, this is your django api response
200
```

```
Output at Server Side

b''
Request Received.....
Responding.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code again...If it is correct, try a different method. I corrected the same issue with a different data-passing method.

Comment: which method did you used?

Comment: apart from get method, i am getting error with post,put,patch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).